# how to render html in summernote?

Tags: javascript, html, summernote

I get html code from summernote like this ：

`<p>Test</p><img style="width: 640px;" src="data:image/jpeg;base64.....>`

Now I want to render it back to summernote in order to edit the content. However `$(“summernote”).code(html)` cannot show images while text is rendered. How can I render images in summernote？

Comment: Hi Chucklai, I am also facing the same issue, I am unable to render or send data (HTML) for updating changes into summernote text area, kindly give some solutions about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem by using pasteHTML parameter. Hope it will help those who have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Jquery and Javascript in a MVC web view.

I SOLVED the problem doing the following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        var htmlWithEncodedTags = '@HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Model.HtmlDescription)';

        // Decode HTML
        var parser = new DOMParser();
        var decodedHtml = parser.parseFromString(htmlWithEncodedTags, "text/html").body.textContent;

$('#summernote').summernote({
            lang: 'it-IT',
            focus: true,
            tabsize: 2,
            height: 300,
            toolbar: [
                ['style', ['style']],
                ['font', ['bold', 'underline', 'clear']],
                ['fontname', ['fontname']],
                ['color', ['color']],
                ['para', ['ul', 'ol', 'paragraph']],
                ['table', ['table']],
                ['insert', ['link', 'picture', 'video']],
                ['view', ['fullscreen', 'codeview', 'help']]
            ],            
        });
        
        $('#summernote').summernote('code', decodedHtml);

});
```